# Marginal profit quick question!

Tags: calculus

So I am doing a question involving marginal profit, I understand how to figure it out, but I am a little confused.

For example, (this isn't the question) say a company sold 50 items. Then I have to use the marginal profit to figure out the change in profit if the company sells one more item a week.

Say the question is something along the lines of 
$P(X) = 25x - 0.04x^{2}$

It would be 
$25 - 0.08(50)$

$25-4 = 21$.

So would the answer be 21, or would it be 25?

Hopefully that makes sense...

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct. If $P(x)$ is the profit function; then $P^{\prime}(x)$, the first derivative of $P(x)$, gives you the Marginal Profit.